# How to find out why was specific package installed by apt

Tags: debian

Just tried to install the following package in my Buster - monitoring-plugins-standard and noticed the following output:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dirmngr gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libarchive13 libassuan0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libcups2 libdbi1 libgpgme11 libksba8 libldb1 libnet-snmp-perl libnpth0 libpq5 libradcli4 libsensors-config libsensors5 libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libtalloc2 libtdb1
  libtevent0 libtirpc-common libtirpc3 libwbclient0 pinentry-curses python-crypto python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb rpcbind samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs smbclient snmp
```

Can someone help me to understand why does apt want to install for example gnupg?

Looking at the recommended packages:

```
Recommends: bind9-host | host, dnsutils, libnet-snmp-perl, rpcbind, smbclient, snmp, sudo, libdbi1 (>= 0.8.4), libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.5), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libmariadb3 (>= 3.0.0), libpq5, libradcli4, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
```

I can't understand which exact package forces gnupg installation. Can someone explain me additional packages installation logic with gnupg package as example? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

`aptitude` can tell you:

```
$ aptitude why monitoring-plugins-standard gnupg
p   monitoring-plugins-standard Recommends smbclient
i A smbclient                   Depends    samba-common (= 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1)
i A samba-common                Recommends samba-common-bin
i A samba-common-bin            Recommends samba-dsdb-modules
i A samba-dsdb-modules          Depends    libgpgme11 (>= 1.2.0)
i A libgpgme11                  Recommends gpgsm
i A gpgsm                       Recommends gnupg (= 2.2.12-1+deb10u1)
```

This works even if none of the packages are installed.

Comment: Very nice answer and solution, thanks a ton.

Comment: @Rimvydas if it works for you and meets with your approval, please consider accepting the answer (using the big checkmark).

Answer (score 4):

Stephen's answer tells you how to find out why. Expanding on this, if you don't want `gnupg` installed, you can prevent that from happening.

Debian packages know several dependency relations, amongst others:

- `a depends b`: package `b` must be installed.
- `a recommends b`: package `b` is optional but recommended. They are installed by default.
- `a suggests b`: package `b` may be useful, but is not installed by default.

Since `gnupg` is recommended (at several points in the chain even), you don't *have* to install it. You can tell apt this by adding `gnupg` to the install command, but appending a `-`. Alternatively, you can skip all recommended packages by using `--no-install-recommends` (for aptitude: `--without-recommends`).

Default:

```
# apt install monitoring-plugins-standard
Suggested packages:
  dbus-user-session pinentry-gnome3 tor rblcheck parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon lrzip
  cups-common libcrypt-des-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl lm-sensors
  snmp-mibs-downloader icinga | icinga2 fping qstat pinentry-doc python-crypto-doc
  heimdal-clients cifs-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dirmngr dnsutils gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
  gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libarchive13 libassuan0 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libdbi1 libgpgme11 libirs161 libjansson4
  libksba8 libldb1 libnet-snmp-perl libnpth0 libpq5 libradcli4 libsensors-config
  libsensors5 libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtevent0
  libwbclient0 monitoring-plugins-basic monitoring-plugins-common
  monitoring-plugins-standard pinentry-curses python-crypto python-gpg python-ldb
  python-samba python-talloc python-tdb rpcbind samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs smbclient snmp sudo
0 upgraded, 54 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 85.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Excluding `gnupg`:

```
# apt install monitoring-plugins-standard gnupg- 
Suggested packages:
  dbus-user-session pinentry-gnome3 tor rblcheck scdaemon lrzip cups-common
  libcrypt-des-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl lm-sensors
  snmp-mibs-downloader icinga | icinga2 fping qstat pinentry-doc python-crypto-doc
  heimdal-clients cifs-utils
Recommended packages:
  gnupg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dirmngr dnsutils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpgconf gpgsm libarchive13 libassuan0
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libdbi1 libgpgme11
  libirs161 libjansson4 libksba8 libldb1 libnet-snmp-perl libnpth0 libpq5 libradcli4
  libsensors-config libsensors5 libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libtalloc2 libtdb1
  libtevent0 libwbclient0 monitoring-plugins-basic monitoring-plugins-common
  monitoring-plugins-standard pinentry-curses python-crypto python-gpg python-ldb
  python-samba python-talloc python-tdb rpcbind samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs smbclient snmp sudo
0 upgraded, 50 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Excluding `smbclient` (which is what pulls in `gnupg`):

```
# apt install monitoring-plugins-standard smbclient-
Suggested packages:
  rblcheck libcrypt-des-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl lm-sensors
  snmp-mibs-downloader icinga | icinga2 fping qstat
Recommended packages:
  smbclient
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dnsutils libdbi1 libirs161 libnet-snmp-perl libpq5 libradcli4 libsensors-config
  libsensors5 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 monitoring-plugins-basic monitoring-plugins-common
  monitoring-plugins-standard rpcbind snmp sudo
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,904 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Excluding all recommends:

```
# apt install --no-install-recommends monitoring-plugins-standard 
Suggested packages:
  icinga | icinga2 fping qstat
Recommended packages:
  dnsutils libnet-snmp-perl rpcbind smbclient snmp sudo libdbi1 libpq5 libradcli4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  monitoring-plugins-basic monitoring-plugins-common monitoring-plugins-standard
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 522 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,088 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

(apt output slightly redacted for brevity)